# Import HTML via link rel not supported in Safari?

Tags: html, import

I'm using this code to import only partial divs from one page into others:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="import" href="html/source.html">
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
    var content = link.import;
    var el = content.querySelector('#mainModals');
    document.body.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
</script>
</body>
```

It works fine in Chrome but it doesn't work in Safari.

The error is: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'content.querySelector')

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is unclear... **how** does it behave in Safari?

Comment: As edited in the question: link.import does not return an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML imports currently [have very limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports) since they are a very new feature (so new that [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/) is only at *Working Draft* status).

They are supported by Chrome 36 onwards and most other browsers that use the Blink browser engine.

IE, Firefox and Safari currently do not support them at all.

Comment: It's more than a year later. Any work-around methods?

Comment: i am also interested in hearing what to do. webkit perhaps? Looks like the answer is still 'no' with ios 10.3 https://webkit.org/status/#feature-html-imports